# Python - Getting 3 random texts from a website

Tags: python

I want to get 3 random texts with python from this website: http://mertatilgan.tk/dork.txt

I tried this :

```
import urllib2
for line in urllib2.urlopen("http://mertatilgan.tk/dork.txt"):
    print line
    while(True):pass
```

It worked but it's getting an only first text from the website. But I need 3 random texts. (Sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: `while(True):pass` what is the purpose of this

Comment: I don't want it to shut down when I start the program.

Comment: It won't "shut down" until it's gone through every `line` in the url you opened.

Comment: Oh...  I removed `while(True):pass` and it print everything and then get closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import random
the_list = urlopen("http://mertatilgan.tk/dork.txt").read().splitlines()
new_list = random.sample(the_list, 3)
```

PS - I'm using urllib to import urlopen because I'm using Python3.

Comment: It work's but there is a problem. First of all I add `print (new_list)` at the end of the code for print the new list. It prints texts with 'b Example: `[b'tek9.php?', b'socsci/events/full_details.php?id=', b'en/publications.php?id=']`

Comment: It's because it's byte stream. It is still a string. You can find more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal). You can decode it to string literal using `text_in_bytes.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

First generate a random number:

```
import random
import urllib2

rand = []
for x in range(3):
    rand[x] = random.randint()

for line,text in enumerate(urllib2.urlopen("http://mertatilgan.tk/dork.txt")):
    if (line == rand[0] || line == rand[1] || line == rand[2])
        print(text)
```

Comment: Python 2.7.14: "There's an error in your program invalid syntax" `....if (line == rand[0] || line == rand[1].....` the second | makes error